# How to remove Dual booting option and partition of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 14.10

First of all, I'd like to state my partitions:

Windows 7 with:

C:\ Windows 7 (pre-existing installation).

D:\ Data (Already exists and has files).

I download Ubuntu 14.10 from a bootable usb. Then I delete Ubuntu's partition using a DVD Windows installer. When I reboot my laptop, Ubuntu's option is still exist and the partition is `Healthy Logical` not `unallocated`. When I click on delete partition, it became as `free space` not `unallocated`.
Also, I tried to merge this partition back to **C:** but there's no `extend volume option` out there. I'm totally confused, how can I get my laptop normal again? How can I delete Ubuntu's partition and Ubuntu's booting option?  I already read this question: [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on). I've done the first answer of that question but the partition and the dual booting option persist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: No, I read it before I post this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all **shrink** that `Logical Partition` and then delete it, it will be transform as **unallocated**. In this situation you can extend the volume of `C: or D:`. Concerning the Ubuntu boot option task, I have deleted the sector `Ubuntu/winboot/wubildr` from cmd by this command `bcdedit /delete {code identifier of the **Real-mode boot sector**}`.  To this moment everything is fine, ubuntu boot option is successfully deleted.